# Labeling every polygon in shapefile except for one in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, sql

I am using ArcMap 10.8.1.

I am trying to create a map of a county which does not need to be labeled since it is for a report concerning that county, but every surrounding county does need a label for reference. I originally approached this in a very convoluted way and just made a different shapefile for each county excluding the county I was working within.

This time I'm trying to put more effort into cleaning the process up a bit. I am trying to use SQL in Labeling to define different classes of features. My initial thought was to just use a simple SQL query to label every polygon that is NOT the one I am currently working in (in this case Ashland).

Is there something wrong with the SQL here or am I missing something else?

I get an error saying an invalid SQL statement was used.

[image]

Comment: Data driven maps can do this automatically using a "does not match" page definition query. I cannot tell if you are using DD maps. Also, "IS" is mostly used with special selects such as IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3):

You almost got it correct, but IS NOT will not work in this case.

Use the below:-

```
COUNTY_NAM <> 'Ashland'
```

Comment: Great, thank you! I always get confused by these.

Answer (score 0):

use this:
`COUNTY_NAM > 'Ashland' OR COUNTY_NAM < 'Ashland'`

Weird but works

Comment: Pretty much the same as `COUNTY_NAM <> 'Ashland'` in the other answer